# Facing CaptureSnapshotReply time out issue while taking data store backup

Tags: opendaylight

Facing issue while taking  data store backup in distribution-karaf-0.5.2-Boron-SR2.

> {"Failed to back up datastore to file ..../distribution-karaf-0.5.2-Boron-SR2/backupFolder/datastorebackup: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for CaptureSnapshotReply","error-info":"error"}]}}

Rest API to get data store backup.

https://localhost:8443/restconf/operations/cluster-admin:backup-datastore

Made cluster set up using distribution-karaf-0.5.2-Boron-SR2 and took called the rest api from leader.

created the datastorebackup folder structure like below

> .../distribution-karaf-0.5.2-Boron-SR2/backupFolder/datastorebackup

**Note**:  In Follower node ODL platform Adapter and ODL Resource manager bundles are failure. After solving the bundle Failure issue and restarting the cluster able to take datastorebackup  successfully.

MDSAL-BACKUP should be successful